# Python how to get variable from between multiple occurrences in string

Tags: python, string, variables

Say I had an input file (temp.tmpl) that looked like this:

```
PTF @
ARB @ C @ @ A @ @ C @
OSN @ B @ @ A @ 
SDA @ B @
CPN 3.23
SNL 3.26
```

And in some other file (candidate.txt):

```
A 3.323 B 4.325 C 6.32 D 723 E 8 F 9 G 1.782
H 7
I 4
J 9
K 10
```

And I wanted to replace A, B , and C with their assigned values.
The way this needs to be accomplished for my task is by finding the
variables A, B, and C by looking for @  @...Then knowing this is obviously a varible.
Then replacing them.  This is what I have tried:

```
reader = open('candidate.txt', 'r')
out = open('output.txt', 'w')

dictionary = dict()
for line in reader.readlines():
    pairs = line.split()
    for variable, value in zip(pairs[::2],pairs[1::2]):
        dictionary[variable] = value

#Now to open the template file
template = open('temp.tmpl', 'r')
for line1 in template:
    if line1[1]:
        confirm = line1.split(' ')[0].lower()
        symbol = line1.split(' ')[1]

        if confirm == 'ptf':
            next(template)

        elif symbol in line1:

            start = line1.find(symbol)+len(symbol)
            end = line1[start:].find(symbol)
            variable = line1[start:start + end].strip()
            print variable
```

And I can not seem to figure out how to handle the lines with multiple sets of variables.
Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Looks like regular expressions can be useful in this case.

Comment: Did you try using a regular expression with `re.sub`?

Comment: Remember to close your file handles.

Answer (score 2):

Using an re?  The question was altered, and here is my modified solution:

```
import re

# Create translation dictionary
codes = re.split(r'\s',open('candidate.txt').read())
trans = dict(zip(codes[::2], codes[1::2]))

outfh = open('out.txt','w')
infh  = open('data.txt')

# First line contains the symbol, but has a trailing space!
symbol = re.sub(r'PTF (.).*',r'\1', infh.readline()[:-1])

for line in infh:
    line = re.sub('\\'+ symbol + r' ([ABC]) ' + '\\' + symbol,
               lambda m: '%s %s %s' % (symbol,trans[m.groups()[0]],symbol),
               line)
    outfh.write(line) 

outfh.close()
```

The `dict` using two `zip`s is a trick to create a dictionary from a [key,value,key,value,...] list

`trans` is a dictionary with the names and their respective values.
`r'@ ([ABC]) @'` captures either A or B or C within the @ signs
The `lambda` function is passed a *match object*, on which we are calling the `groups()` method.  This returns a tuple of the matching parentheses groups, in this case either A or B or C.  We use this for the key to the dictionary `trans`, and hence replace it with the value.

Comment: Thank you for your post because it really helps and im learning a good bit about re's now, but how would the syntax change if from the first line of the input file, @ was defined as symbol and now everywhere in your code, @ was replaced by the variable 'symbol'...could this still work ?

Comment: Yes, provided the symbol was not an RE meta-character (special character) like * or . or [ or { or + or ? and so on.  If in doubt, place a \ to its left.  This also applies if the symbol if held in a variable.

Comment: hmmm...let me edit my original post to include everything i am trying to do

Comment: On further consideration, look-arounds could simplify the lambda (but make the re more complex)

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't simple string replacement work for you?

```
>>> 'foo @ A @ @ B @'.replace('@ A @','12345')
'foo 12345 @ B @'
```

It will replace all occurrences of `@ A @` to whatever you want. You can apply it multiple times, perhaps once for every variable:

```
# a dictionary of variable values,
# you'll probably read this from somewhere
values = { 'A': '123', 'B': '456' }

# iterate over variable names
for varname in values: 
    pattern = str.format('@ {} @', varname)
    value = values[varname]

    # data is your input string
    data = data.replace(pattern, value)
```